Maven surefire overwrites the logs for flaky tests on rerunFailingTestsCount
I'm using maven-surefire-plugin to rerunFailingTests for the failing tests. If the test fails in first attempt and pass on the later attempts, the logs(*.txt, *-output.txt) from the /target/surefire-reports/ are not preserved. It seems that maven overwrites these logs. Is there a way I can preserve these logs?

No, this would require a change in Maven Surefire. Are you willing to provide a PR for that?
